# Siriproxy Server Error

Tags: rvm, raspberry-pi, siri

I am trying to run Siriproxy on a fresh Raspberry Pi.

I have followed this tutorial step by step: http://www.hometoys.com/emagazine.php?art_id=2090

Everything looked to install 100%. But on the last step I tried to run 'rvmsudo siriproxy server' I get this error below.

```
siri@raspberrypi:~/SiriProxy$ rvmsudo siriproxy server
/home/siri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `initialize': No    such file or directory - /root/.siriproxy/config.ym              l (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/siri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `open'
    from /home/siri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `load_file'
    from /home/siri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.3/lib/siriproxy/command_line.rb:143:in `parse_options'
    from /home/siri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.3/lib/siriproxy/command_line.rb:33:in `initialize'
    from /home/siri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.3/bin/siriproxy:6:in `new'
    from /home/siri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.3/bin/siriproxy:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/siri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@SiriProxy/bin/siriproxy:23:in `load'
    from /home/siri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@SiriProxy/bin/siriproxy:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you ran the sections involving `cp ~/SiriProxy/config.example.yml ~/.siriproxy/config.yml` you created these directories in your user directory, not in the root directory where it is looking. The ~/ symbol is shorthand for a home directory. Try learning how basic linux navigation works and matching up where your config.yml files should be stored-- e.g., root vs user directories.